# KryoNet - Sending packets to Android clients

Tags: java, android, networking, kryo, kryonet

I am developing an *Android* app which has to connect clients to my server for sending/receiving different sort of packets. To achieve that, I am using the *KryoNet* library. My clients connect themself to the server and send their own packets successfully. But my problem is that the server seems to failed at responding to them. I have registered these packets in the same order on the server side and the client side and I use the `connection` parameter of the overrided `reveived` method from `kryonet.Listener` to respond (e.g. `connection.sendUDP(...)`). I have an *Android* **5.0.2**, I use the **2.22.0-RC1** version of *KryoNet* both on the server side and the client side... With the option `Log.set(Log.LEVEL_DEBUG)` enabled, I can see that the server starts to write a packet
(**DEBUG: [kryo] write: PacketMovement**) but I receive nothing.

I would really appreciate any help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for people having the same problem : [https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/pull/111](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/pull/111#issuecomment-198682109).